# Excel: Move values instead of replacing

Tags: excel, formula

Q: If I have a value in Cell A1 and want to automatically have that value moved to another cell once I type a new value in cell A1, how do I do that? I don't want the value to disappear, only move to a new location.

I do not know VBA so this will need to be a formula.

Comment: Easy to do with *VBA* or manually, not possible with just a formula.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is possible with functions.  You could set the target cell as equal to input cell and then set conditional formatting on the input cell to in effect make the input text invisible once you enter a certain value.  But I'm not sure if that is quite what you're asking for.